# Evaluating financial plans

Tags: finance, economics

I am solving the following problem:

> 30 y.o. Jack is working a manual job, earning only 8000USD yearly and
>   he isn't expecting any wage increase till his retirement at age 63.
>   However, he is thinking about going to college, which will cost
>   1000USD yearly. College will take 3 years. After finishing the college, he would > be able to earn
>   12 000USD yearly until his retirement age. He can't work when
>   studying. Interest rate is 4% p.a.
>
> Is it worth it for Jack to go the college? All financial transactions
>   are realized at the end of each year.

a) (staying in work) $P= 8000*\frac{1-(1+0,04)^{-33}}{0,04}=145181,16$

b) (going to college) = $(-1000)*\frac{1-(1+0,04)^{-3}}{0,04}+12000*\frac{1-(1+0,04)^{-30}}{0,04}*\frac{1}{(1+0,04)^3}
= 181 695, 5646$

Is my solution correct?

Thanks

Comment: I assume you just want to use present value of future Cashflows?

Comment: @NazimJ yes, that was my idea, but I was not sure if I should use the formula for future value or this one which I used

Comment: @NazimJ Can you help me?

Comment: It looks very right to me. Do you have any reasons/hints that your calculation is not right?

Comment: @callculus because I was not sure if I am supposed to calculate the future value of future cashflows or the present value of the cashflows

Comment: Both methods leads to the same result if the periods have equal lengths: $C_0^1<C_0^2\Leftrightarrow C_n^1<C_n^2$, where $C_t^k$ is the value at time $t$ of the payment flow $k$

Comment: Oh, okay thank you

Comment: @Daniel You´re welcome